# When imageCache.clear,CustomScrollView doesn't maintain image size in scrollView anymore in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm facing a problem, When I call PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear(), CustomScrollView doesn't maintain image size in scrollView anymore.

I know the cache is cleared. but I'd like to maintain image size in CustomScrollView, How to solve it? Thanks a lot.

This is a minimum reproducible demo when push to a new page, it will `PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear()` and then back to the previous page, because the image is cleaned up, the maxScrollExtent changes and causes scrolling. If I give the image fixed height, it works very well.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: controller,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              height: 400,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Image.network(
              'https://flutter.dev/assets/homepage/carousel/slide_1-layer_1-d5abecee7978584303d3e0c8060e79eca6265779eadac5929c651ee0c4ec6a96.png',
              width: double.infinity,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => print(
                  'maxScrollExtent:${controller.position.maxScrollExtent}'),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue[200],
                height: 400,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => pushPage(context),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue[300],
                height: 400,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void pushPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (context) {
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
            print('clean chache');
            PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear();
          });
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My Page')),
            body: Container(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```